# First cohomology of a cochain complex depends on field?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

Let $\Delta$ be a simplicial complex on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and let us consider the cochain complex of $\Delta$ over $\mathbb{K}$

$$0 \rightarrow C^{-1} \xrightarrow{\delta^{-1}} C^{0} \xrightarrow{\delta^{0}} \cdots\rightarrow C^{d}\xrightarrow{\delta^{d}} 0.$$

Let us denote the $i$-th reduced cohomology of $\Delta$ over $\mathbb{K}$ by $H^i (\Delta; \mathbb{K}) := \ker(\delta^{i+1}) / \mathrm{Im} (\delta^{i})$. Elements of $\ker(\delta^{i+1})$ are called $i$-cocycles and elements of $\mathrm{Im} (\delta^{i})$ are called $i$-coboundaries.

Does $H^1 (\Delta; \mathbb{K})$ depend on $\mathbb{K}$? That is, if I find that $H^1 (\Delta; \mathbb{F}_2)$ is not $0$ (showing an element that is a cycle but not a boundary, with respect to $\mathbb{F}_2$), then there is any known result that guarantees that $H^1 (\Delta; \mathbb{K})$ is not $0$ for any field $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: If the original chain complex is only defined over a field $K$, then it is not clear to me how you work with it over other fields, except possibly for field extensions or (if you're lucky) subfields of $K$. If the original chain complex is defined over the integers, then you can consider it over any ring you want. Maybe that's what you mean -- you want the original complex defined over $\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: $H^1(\Delta,\mathbb{K})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, whereas $H^1(\Delta,\mathbb{XYZ})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{XYZ}$. So they are different mathematical structures entirely. So I think you need to clarify what you mean by "depend on $\mathbb{K}$", outside of simply the issue of whether they are $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the cohomology certainly depends on the field. For example consider $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (which can be triangulated, so you can see this as a simplicial complex), then $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2; \mathbb{F}_2) = \mathbb{F}_2$, however $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2; \mathbb{K}) = 0$ if the characteristic of $\mathbb{K}$ is not $2$ (e.g. if $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$).

You do have the Universal Coefficient Theorem though, which implies for example that if $\operatorname{char} \mathbb{K} = 2$, then
$$H^i(\Delta; \mathbb{K}) \cong H^i(\Delta; \mathbb{F}_2) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} \mathbb{K}.$$
But you can't expect information about $H^1(\Delta;\mathbb{F}_2)$ to give you information about cohomology over all the other fields.

Comment: You are right. Your example fits perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Define the chain complex $0 \to \mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z} \to 0$ where the map is multiplication by 2. Now compare what happens if you tensor with $\mathbf{Q}$ with what happens if you tensor with $\mathbf{F}_2$.

Comment: What simplicial complex are you using?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't come from a simplicial complex -- I didn't read the question closely enough -- but the spirit of the answer applies just the same. The cohomology of a cochain complex over $\mathbf{Z}$ can have torsion, which means that it can lead to zero or nonzero answers after tensoring with different fields.